# Example of a continuous function $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{1/n}^1 f \, dx = 0$ for all $n$ but $\int_0^1 f \, dx$ DNE?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, improper-integrals

I'm looking for an example of a continuous function $f:(0,1) \rightarrow 
\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{1/n}^1 f \, dx = 0$ for all $n$ but $\int_0^1 f \, dx$ does not exist.

I know we can consider the function $F(x) = \int_x^1 f(x) \, dx$.  So the above would be equivalent to finding $F(x)$ s.t. $F(1/n) = 0$ for all $n$, but $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} F(x)$ does not exist.  Then taking the derivative of $F$ we will get $f$.

Thanks...

Comment: Does DNE mean that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ does not exists?

Comment: Or do you mean that $\int_0^1$ does not exist?

Comment: Define a function $f$ which oscillates and changes sign for $0$ for $x= 1/n$. Choose the function, e.g., on $(1/(n-1), 1/n)$ as a constant such that its integral cancels with the one of $f$ on $(1/n, 1/(n+1))$

Comment: (ok, the instruction in my comment do not yield a continuous function, but that's easy to fix)

Comment: Changed to reflect that $\int_0^1$ should be the integral that does not exist (DNE).

Comment: $$ 1 + (-1) + 2 + (-2) + 3 + (-3) + \cdots + n + (-n) = 0 \text{ for all values of } n \in \mathbb N $$ $$ \text{but the sum of this infinite series does not exist.} $$
So I would seek some function $f$ for which $ \displaystyle \int_{1/n}^1 f(x) \, dx ={}$the partial sum of this series. And that's easy if you allow piecewise definitions, and takes a bit more thought if you use oscillating trigonometric functions. $\qquad$

Comment: Echoing @Thomas. Do piecewise steps where the integral merely alternates signs (with the same absolute value). Clearly that doesn't converge. Remember: infinite sums are not that different from integrals. This paves a way for a lot of counterexamples in measure theory/real analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $F(x)$ be defined as $F(x)=\sin(\pi /x)$ for $x\in (0,1)$. Clearly, $F(x)$ is differentiable for $x\in(0,1)$ with

$$f(x)\equiv -F'(x) =\frac{\pi \cos(\pi/x)}{x^2}$$

Note that $F'(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.

We have, therefore, that

$$\int_{1/n}^1 \frac{\pi \cos(\pi/x)}{x^2}\,dx=-\left.\sin(\pi/x)\right|_{x=1/n}^1=0$$

for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Moreover, the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\pi \cos(\pi/x)}{x^2}\,dx$ fails to exist.

> Finally, $f(x)=\frac{\pi \cos(\pi/x)}{x^2}\in C(0,1)$ such that
>
> $$\int_{1/n}^1 f(x)\,dx=0$$
>
> for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and such that $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ fails to exist.